# PHP - Get all characters before an array of characters

Tags: php, regex

I have two strings:

`email-info` and `info/email`

I need to retrieve all of the characters before `-` or `/` appears, so that, after being formatted, the strings look like this:

`email` and `info`

What is  the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty trivial for regular expressions. That is to say you could use something else (i.e. string functions).

Nonetheless, here's an example using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
$parts = preg_split('/[-\/]/', $string);
```

Comment: I am hoping to accommodate for more than these two characters. Thanks Jason. Building my regex skills, one pattern at a time :)

Comment: In that case, `preg_split()` is the way to go. Just keep adding to the grouping and remember to escape any regex syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Jason's right. Here's a way to do it with string functions:

```
$str1 = "email-info";
$result = substr($str1, 0, strlen($str1) - strpos('-'));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to account for the `/` character

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [split method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)

```
$StringYouWant = split($StringNeedsSplitting, '(-|/)')[0]
```

Comment: Looks clean, although `split` is deprecated moving forward, so I'd prefer to stay away

Comment: `explode()` is an alternative, although note that it does not allow a pattern.

Comment: Ah.. I missed that big sign :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = preg_replace('/[-\/](.*)$/', '', $email);
```